# How can I properly create /dev/dvd?

Tags: 12.04, udev

Certain programs look for `/dev/dvd` by default to find DVDs.  When I first boot my computer without a DVD inserted, `/dev/dvd` exists and points to the correct place (`/dev/sr0`).  However, when I insert a DVD, `/dev/dvd` disappears.  I'd like it to stick around so I don't have to navigate to `/dev/sr0` in programs that are looking for DVDs.  How do I ensure that the `/dev/dvd` symlink exists and points to the right place?

It looks like I can add something to `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rules`.  [This site](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) gives a couple of examples, but the `70-persistent-cd.rules` file says "add the ENV{GENERATED}=1 flag to your own rules", which isn't part of the examples.  The `man 7 udev` page is impenetrable to me, and I'm not convinced the linked page gives 100% of the information I need.

So, what can I do on a modern, Ubuntu 12.04 (or later) system to make `/dev/dvd` always exist and point to the right device?

EDIT: Is it as simple as adding `ENV{GENERATED}=1` to the rules in the linked page, something like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr0", SYMLINK+="dvd", GROUP="cdrom", ENV{GENERATED}=1
```

Is that the right information for modern Ubuntu?  What is `ENV{GENERATED}` doing there, when it wasn't generated, but hand-written?

Comment: I ran into the same problem on a Dell Inspiron 660s. Wish there was a better answer for this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This tutorial explain very nice how to do what you want:

- [Creating Custom Symlinks to Devices](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/development/chapter07/symlinks.html)

According to it, there are two approaches to creating symlinks. The first one is to use the model name and the serial number:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="...", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="...", ENV{GENERATED}="1", SYMLINK+="dvd"
```

This way, the symlink will stay correct even if you move the drive to different positions on the IDE bus, but the `/dev/dvd` symlink won't be created if you replace the drive.

The second one is based on the location of the device on the bus:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_TYPE}=="...", ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-...", ENV{GENERATED}="1", SYMLINK+="dvd"
```

This way, the symlink will stay correct even if you replace drives with different models, but place them to the same positions on the IDE bus. The `ENV{ID_TYPE}` key makes sure that the symlink disappears if you put something other than a DVD in that position on the bus.

You can find the values for `ID_MODEL`, `ID_SERIAL`, `ID_TYPE` and `ID_PATH` using the following command (the `udevtest` command as in tutorial doesn't work - anymore ? - in Ubuntu):

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=sr0
```

The `SUBSYSTEM=="block"` key is needed in order to avoid matching SCSI generic devices. Without it, in the case with SCSI DVD, the symlink will sometimes point to the correct `/dev/sr0` devices, and sometimes to `/dev/sg0`, which is wrong.

The `ENV{GENERATED}="1"` key is needed to prevent the udev `75-cd-aliases-generator.rules` file from overriding your custom rules.

Comment: Thanks for all the info.  I went to try out some of these rules, but found that my `/dev/dvd` symlink magically fixed itself sometime in the last few months.  I also read in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/926976) that `/dev/dvd`'s days are numbered.  Oh well.  For now, your answer seems to give all the info necessary to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on a fedora forum may helps:

Create a shell script file 
In that file, put:

```
#!/bin/bash
ln -s /dev/sr0 /dev/dvd
```

Make sure the file is execlutable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

If you're going to use the rc.local route, you also need to do this, as root:

```
systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

because it's not enabled by default

***source:***http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=295048

---------The preferred way these days would be a UDev rule--------------

Based on /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules, which creates the /dev/cdrom symbolic link, try adding a file /etc/udev/rules.d/60-dvd.rules containing:

```
KERNEL=="sr0", SYMLINK+="dvd", OPTIONS+="link_priority=-100"
```